# observable onComplete not called when nested observable calls are made

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

For a nested observable, the nested observable's onComplete is not called when the same code is written in Kotlin.

The nested observable onNext gets called, but does not call onComplete and the call gets completed.
There is no exception thrown at either of the .subscribe calls.

Is there any equivalent to Coroutine code

> val listItem = async {
> ...
> }
> val data = listItem.await()

output sequence for the following bit of code is:
// observable 1 completed
// observable 2 completed

```
getListObservable  
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  
.observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())  
.subscribe(  
 {  
   listItem ->  
      getListItemParams(listItem.id)   
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  
     .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())    
     .subscribe(  
        {  paramList: List<BaseObservable?> ->  
        },  
        { throwable: Throwable ->  
        },  
        {  
           // observable 2 completed  
        },  
        Disposable? ->  

       }  
     )  
 },  
 throwable: Throwable? ->  

 },  
 {  
    // observable 1 completed  
 },  
  Disposable? ->  

  }  
)
```

I have tried wrapping the nested called in a `CompositeDisposable`, but with same results.

**update**:
`getListItemParams(listItem.id)` is a call to Room db query which returns an Onservable to subscribe to.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = :id")
fun getListItemParams(id:Int): Observable<List<DataPoint>>
```

Comment: Please show the implementation of `getListItemParams`.

Comment: One of the mobile databases act as infinite queries because they provide live change updates. Can't remember if it is Room or not. Try using `Single<List<DataPoint>>` as a return type.

Comment: @akarnokd can you post your comment as an answer, I have managed to solve the issue by using `Single<List<DataPoint>>`